# Batch file to copy specific user defined directory to destination

Tags: batch-file, directory, copy, user-input

I'm working on an easier way to install our ROV control software. I've managed almost all of what I want to do, but we have 40 systems each with unique input folders that have to be in `C:\Innovator\Input`.

Each system has a unique `Input` folder containing all relevant files and variables for that control system.

I found a nice script that allows the user to define which input folder they want to have copied to the folder `C:\Innovator`. But I dont know how to make the script copy the specified `INN_01` to `INN_41` folder to folder `C:\Innovator`, see below.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

```
echo.
echo.
echo ===========================================================
echo Starting on !date! !time! on !Computername!
echo ===========================================================
echo.

goto :main


:main
setlocal

set /P innovator=Please type the ID of the system you would like to restore (ie, INN_03): 
set innovatorDir=D:\files\Innovator\Systems_inputs\!innovator!\
set app=setup.exe /cd
set log=c:\logs.txt


echo. Starting on !date! !time! on !Computername! >> !log!
echo.
echo The input folder you selected is for: !innovator!
echo.

goto :user

:user

set /p answer=Is this correct (Y/N)? 
echo.

if /i !answer!==y goto :yes (
) else ( 
    echo.
    echo Ok. Let's try again and this time get it right ya MONG^^!
    echo.
    Pause
    cls
    goto :beginning
    )
)

:yes

for /d %%i in ( !innovatordir!*media1\setup ) do (
    start !app!
)

endlocal
goto :eof
```

Comment: What about using [copy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771997.aspx) or [xcopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254.aspx)? Open a command prompt window and enter `copy /?` or `xcopy /?` to get short help about those 2 commands.

Comment: I know about xcopy but I'm not sure how to modify the above script to make it work.  I know I need to change the  set app and set log and modify the :yes but I just don't know how to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a batch file for what I think you want. Lines starting with `rem` are comment lines.

```
@echo off
echo.
echo.
echo ===========================================================
echo Starting on %DATE% %TIME% on %COMPUTERNAME%
echo ===========================================================
echo.
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:UserChoice
set InnovatorID=00
set /P "FolderID=Please type ID (01..41) of input folder, e.g. 03: "
rem Append a leading zero if just a single character (digit) was entered by user.
if "%FolderID:~-1%"=="%FolderID%" set "FolderID=0%FolderID%"
set "FolderName=C:\Innovator\Input\INN_%FolderID%"
echo.
rem Verify the existence of directory selected by ID.
if not exist "%FolderName%" (
    echo "%FolderID%" is not a valid ID. Valid is 01 ... 41.
    echo.
    set Answer=y
    set /P "Answer=Retry [y/n]: "
    if /I "!Answer!"=="y" (
        echo.
        echo.
        goto UserChoice
    )
    rem User decided to abort and therefore exit batch task.
    endlocal
    goto :EOF
)

rem Ask user for confirmation before processing. The default answer
rem is "y" (yes) and therefore user needs to press only RETURN/ENTER.
set Answer=y
set /P "Answer=Is ID %FolderID% correct [y/n]? "
if /I "%Answer%"=="y" goto Processing

echo.
echo OK, let's try again and this time get it right^^!
echo.
echo.
goto UserChoice

:Processing
set "log=%TEMP%\InputFolderCopy.log"
echo INN_%FolderID% copied on %DATE% %TIME% on %COMPUTERNAME%.1>>"%log%"
echo.
echo The input folder you selected is: INN_%FolderID%
echo.
xcopy "%FolderName%" "C:\Innovator" /E /H /I /K /Q /R /Y 1>nul
echo Processing finished.
echo.
endlocal
```

Modify the line with `set "log=..."` to define name of log file and storage location which records each copy process with a single line. The log file should be most likely stored on a public server share and not in the local directory for temporary files.